# Unity3d + Vuforia Augmented Reality (AR) objects intersection

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, unityscript, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to make a game, where a kid has an image (of grass, for example) and a card (a monster). The monster should appear on the grass only if the kid puts card on it, and disappears on removing.

Is it possible to achieve such behavior (to find out if one tracking object is on another)? and if it is, how can I implement it?

I have already successfully setup vuforia AR environment, so I can see monster sitting on the card in realtime. My idea now is to tie invisible body to the grass, so I can check if objects (card and grass) intersect in space and show a monster if they do. Is it a right approach? If so, how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Add your monster prefab (or model) as a child to your `ImageTarget` game object. When `ImageTarget` is recognized, it will be visible and when it's visible, all of it's child objects are also visible. When `ImageTarget` becomes invisible, all of it's child objects become invisible too. Basically, `ImageTarget`'s visibility determines whether it's child objects are visible.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but problem is not in tracking objects or visualization. It's done and works great. Problem is to find out if card for monster is laying on the grass image or not. Any suggestions?

Comment: @WantToKnow Colliders.

Comment: Trigger colliders to be more precise.